# I need help in converting html template to wordpress themes

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an HTML template which i want to convert to WordPress theme. Though i have converted it already, but i don't know how to convert the contact form area to collect the data from the users and save to the database/admin panel on WordPress.

```
<div class="contact-form">
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Names" id="contact-name">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="contact-email">
        <br>
        <br>
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="100%" rows="9" id="contact-message" placeholder="We want to 
           hear from you!">
        </textarea>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" id="contact-submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>                                                                                         
</div>
```

Comment: You can use Contact Form 7 plugin for all sorts of forms. After creating the form, just embed it to your page with its shortcode. Using this method, you can embed the same form on multiple pages / posts etc. as well.

Comment: Thanks, but Is the shortcode going inside the HTML template?

Comment: No, shortcode will go inside the wordpress' page/post content